# How to setup a jasper report with any length of height?

Tags: jasper-reports

Say that a jasper report should be generated to a thermal printer. The detail band may be 1 row or 200+ rows.

How to generate jasper report with its height fitting to the row count instead of printing white-spaces in the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `pageHeight` to just one row and then use

```
isIgnorePagination="true"
```

> When **isIgnorePagination** is true the report will be generated in a
>   **single page**.

Hence, if just one row, it will have the height of one row, if more rows it will not create new pages but generate a continues layout.

For example see: http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/nopagebreak/